# Am I incorrectly implementing IntoIterator for a reference or is this a Rust bug that should be reported?

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Furthering the example of implementing `IntoIterator` for a wrapped vector as per [the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), I am also trying to **implement IntoIterator for a reference** to the wrapper, as per [the following code (Playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3395a2a5afe87741df18d1bcf91ecd94):

```
struct VecWrapper(Vec<i32>);

impl VecWrapper {
    fn iter(&'static self) -> Iter {
        Iter(Box::new(self.0.iter()))
    }
}

struct Iter(Box<Iterator<Item = &'static i32>>);

impl Iterator for Iter {
    type Item = &'static i32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.0.next()
    }
}

impl IntoIterator for &'static VecWrapper {
    type Item = &'static i32;
    type IntoIter = Iter;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // let test = vec![1, 2, 3]; // obviously, works
    let test = VecWrapper(vec![1, 2, 3]); // not working
    for v in &test {
        println!("{}", v);
    }
}
```

Although the implementation compiles, the attempt to use it in `main` doesn't with the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `test` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:31:14
   |
31 |     for v in &test {
   |              ^^^^^
   |              |
   |              borrowed value does not live long enough
   |              argument requires that `test` is borrowed for `'static`
...
34 | }
   | - `test` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This code is greatly simplified from what I would actually want to use as to using only `'static` lifetimes, using an existing contained type, and using `i32` for the inner (iterated) type, but it is boiled down to show just the problem.

---

The accepted answer solves the first part of the problem as to not using `'static` and using `+ 'a` with traits. I still am having a problem with the actual code, which is a `LazyList` implementation.  I've posted that as [Am I incorrectly implementing IntoIterator for a reference to a LazyList implementation or is this a Rust bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687955/am-i-incorrectly-implementing-intoiterator-for-a-reference-to-a-lazylist-impleme).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have correctly implemented the iterator for references to `VecWrapper`s that *live for the entire length of the program* — the `'static` lifetime.

Chances are you want to have a generic lifetime. That lifetime will then be provided a concrete lifetime, unique to each instantiation. Usually, we are lazy and just give this lifetime the name `'a`:

```
struct VecWrapper(Vec<i32>);

impl VecWrapper {
    fn iter(&self) -> Iter {
        Iter(Box::new(self.0.iter()))
    }
}

struct Iter<'a>(Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a i32> + 'a>);

impl<'a> Iterator for Iter<'a> {
    type Item = &'a i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.0.next()
    }
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a VecWrapper {
    type Item = &'a i32;
    type IntoIter = Iter<'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test = VecWrapper(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    for v in &test {
        println!("{}", v);
    }
}
```

Important changes:

- `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a i32> + 'a>` - `+ 'a` was added. This is needed because a *trait object* will assume that there are no interior values that reference anything with a short lifetime.
- The `Item` type is now `&'a i32`.
- A generic lifetime is declared in many places and provided in many others (`<'a>`).

See also:

- [Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42028470/155423)

---

Normally, there wouldn't be a reason to use a trait object here. I'd just embed the iterator directly:

```
struct Iter<'a>(std::slice::Iter<'a, i32>);
```

This avoids the need to have any indirection, which is unused in this case anyway. Additionally, it more obviously couples the lifetimes.

Comment: I already knew how to implement using `'a` instead of `'static` as I mentioned in the question as to just simplifying and already had a version using `'a` in the same places as you do; what I missed was the `+ 'a` in the definition for the `Iter struct` (your first point).  For that, I thank you very much.  For others reading this, as @Shpmaster saids, using `'static` doesn't work here, even with the `+`, as the general use in an iteration/for loop will be inside another function/block.

Comment: While I agree that your last suggestion may make the code clearer as to lifetimes, it requires a deep knowledge of the internals of the standard library and increases the complexity of initializing as in something like `std::slice::Iter { ptr: self.0[0], end: (self.0[0] as *const i32).offset(self.0.len() as isize), _marker: std::marker::PhantomData }`, which isn't possible since the `ptr`, `end`, and `_marker` fields are private and can't be initialized outside the module  That's not usable, is it?

Comment: @GordonBGood *it requires a deep knowledge of the internals of the standard library* — what? [Just... call the normal method](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=fe12ab6a13ba9e6ec722d430bb1bc20a&version=stable).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot that `Vec` is overloaded to call through to produce the slice `Iter`; but in order to declare the Iter wrapper to contain this, it still requires we know that `Vec::iter()` produces and in what module it can be found.

Comment: @GordonBGood *requires we know that `Vec::iter()` produces* — which is available in the API docs and from the compiler. It's also part of the public API, so it can't really change.