# Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm applying a closure on the iterator and I want to use stable, so I want to return a boxed `Iterator`. The obvious way to do so is the following:

```
struct Foo;

fn into_iterator(myvec: &Vec<Foo>) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &Foo>> {
    Box::new(myvec.iter())
}
```

This fails because the borrow checker cannot infer the appropriate lifetimes.

After some research, I've found [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423), which brought me to adding `+ 'a`:

```
fn into_iterator<'a>(myvec: &'a Vec<Foo>) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a Foo> + 'a> {
    Box::new(myvec.iter())
}
```

But I don't understand

- What this does
- And why it is needed here

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is one thing that is easily overlooked: if you have a trait `Bar` and you want to have a boxed trait object `Box<dyn Bar>`, the compiler automatically adds a `'static` lifetime bound (as specified in [RFC 599](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0599-default-object-bound.md)). This means that `Box<dyn Bar>` and `Box<dyn Bar + 'static>` are equivalent!

In your case, the compiler automatically adds the static bound such that this ...

```
fn into_iterator(myvec: &Vec<Foo>) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &Foo>>
```

... is equivalent to that:

```
fn into_iterator(myvec: &Vec<Foo>) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'static>
```

Now lifetime elision rules kick in and "connect" the two lifetime-slots, such that the above code is equivalent to:

```
fn into_iterator<'a>(myvec: &'a Vec<Foo>) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a Foo> + 'static>
```

But the type `Iter<'a, Foo>` (the specific iterator type for `Vec<Foo>`) obviously does not satisfy the bound `'static` (because it is borrowing the `Vec<Foo>`)! So we have to tell the compiler that we don't want the default `'static` bound by specifying our own lifetime bound:

```
fn into_iterator<'a>(myvec: &'a Vec<Foo>) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a>
```

Now the compiler knows that the trait object is only valid for the lifetime `'a`. Note that we don't explicitly need to annotate the lifetime of the associated `Item` type! Lifetime elision rules take care of that.

Comment: Oh of course! I completely forgot that it isn't about Foo but the Iterator itself; I first thought the lifetime bound was on a struct... Thanks for clarifying this!