# Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime when sharing self reference

Tags: concurrency, rust

This is an experiment I'm doing while learning Rust and following *Programming Rust*.

Here's a [link to the code in the playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=6e08c6c8dde0c3fddaed387e3c82df4f&version=stable).

I have a struct (`Thing`) with some inner state (`xs`). A `Thing` should be created with `Thing::new` and then `start`ed, after which the user should choose to call some other function like `get_xs`.

But! In `start` 2 threads are `spawn`ed which call other methods on the `Thing` instance that could mutate its inner state (say, add elements to `xs`), so they need a reference to `self` (hence the `Arc`). However, this causes a lifetime conflict:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:18:30
   |
18 |         let self1 = Arc::new(self);
   |                              ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined 
on the method body at 17:5...
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 | /     fn start(&self) -> io::Result<Vec<JoinHandle<()>>> {
18 | |         let self1 = Arc::new(self);
19 | |         let self2 = self1.clone();
20 | |
...  |
33 | |         Ok(vec![handle1, handle2])
34 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected &Thing, found &Thing)
  --> src/main.rs:18:30
   |
18 |         let self1 = Arc::new(self);
   |                              ^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/main.rs:23:20: 25:14 
self1:std::sync::Arc<&Thing>]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:23:14
   |
23 |             .spawn(move || loop {
   |              ^^^^^
```

Is there a way of spawning the state-mutating threads and still give back ownership of `thing` after running `start` to the code that's using it?

```
use std::io;
use std::sync::{Arc, LockResult, RwLock, RwLockReadGuard};
use std::thread::{Builder, JoinHandle};

struct Thing {
    xs: RwLock<Vec<String>>
}

impl Thing {

    fn new() -> Thing {
        Thing {
            xs: RwLock::new(Vec::new()),
        }
    }

    fn start(&self) -> io::Result<Vec<JoinHandle<()>>> {
        let self1 = Arc::new(self);
        let self2 = self1.clone();

        let handle1 = Builder::new()
            .name("thread1".to_owned())
            .spawn(move || loop {
                 self1.do_within_thread1();
            })?;

        let handle2 = Builder::new()
            .name("thread2".to_owned())
            .spawn(move || loop {
                self2.do_within_thread2();
            })?;

        Ok(vec![handle1, handle2])
    }

    fn get_xs(&self) -> LockResult<RwLockReadGuard<Vec<String>>> {
        return self.xs.read();
    }

    fn do_within_thread1(&self) {
        // read and potentially mutate self.xs
    }

    fn do_within_thread2(&self) {
        // read and potentially mutate self.xs
    }
}

fn main() {
    let thing = Thing::new();
    let handles = match thing.start() {
        Ok(hs) => hs,
        _ => panic!("Error"),
    };

    thing.get_xs();

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I think I get what it's saying. The self references - through the Arc - could live longer than self itself"_ Not at all! `Arc::new(self)` is creating a value of type `Arc<&Self>`, which is still tied to the internal reference's lifetime. A method taking `&self` cannot magically make a value live longer. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42028470/1233251) might be useful.

Comment: @E_net4 I'll just remove that part from the question. I didn't mean what you understood haha, and it's not relevant to the discussion. I still have to wrap my mind around lifetimes.

Comment: @E_net4 I refactored the code according to your suggestions to make it less distracting. The compiler error message and the playground link were updated also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that the value passed to the `Arc` must live the `'static` lifetime. This is because spawning a thread, be it with [`std::thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) or [`std::thread::Builder`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Builder.html), requires the passed closure to live this lifetime, thus enabling the thread to "live freely" beyond the scope of the spawning thread.

Let us expand the prototype of the `start` method:

```
fn start<'a>(&'a self: &'a Thing) -> io::Result<Vec<JoinHandle<()>>> { ... }
```

The attempt of putting a `&'a self` into an `Arc` creates an `Arc<&'a Thing>`, which is still constrained to the lifetime `'a`, and so cannot be moved to a closure that needs to live longer than that. Since we cannot move out `&self` either, the solution is not to use `&self` for this method. Instead, we can make `start` accept an `Arc` directly:

```
fn start(thing: Arc<Self>) -> io::Result<Vec<JoinHandle<()>>> {
    let self1 = thing.clone();
    let self2 = thing;

    let handle1 = Builder::new()
        .name("thread1".to_owned())
        .spawn(move || loop {
             self1.do_within_thread1();
        })?;

    let handle2 = Builder::new()
        .name("thread2".to_owned())
        .spawn(move || loop {
            self2.do_within_thread2();
        })?;

    Ok(vec![handle1, handle2])
}
```

And pass reference-counted pointers at the consumer's scope:

```
let thing = Arc::new(Thing::new());
let handles = Thing::start(thing.clone()).unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Error"));

thing.get_xs().unwrap();

for handle in handles {
    handle.join().unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=cba014447935bb447c37802229828927&version=stable). At this point the program will compile and run (although the workers are in an infinite loop, so the playground will kill the process after the timeout).