# Prevent 'static lifetime requirement in Rc<Trait>

Tags: static, rust, traits, lifetime

Where is the `'static` lifetime requirement coming from when using a `trait` type in `std::rc::Rc` and how can I prevent it?  E.g. when trying to compile this code

```
trait Handler{}

fn add(a: std::rc::Rc<Handler>) {
}

fn main() {
    add(0);
}
```

rust reports

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> test.rs:7:9
...
  = note: expected type `std::rc::Rc<Handler + 'static>`
             found type `{integer}`
```

NOTE: the error itself is expected; I am just interested in the `Handler + 'static` diagnostic output.  The Real program creates instances of a `trait` type, stores them into a `HashMap` and runs a type specific function on it.  It fails to compile with

```
| - borrowed value only lives until here
|
= note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

at this place.

#### Second example

The following code is more real-world and demonstrates the issue perhaps better:

```
trait Handler {
}

struct SomeHandler<'a>(&'a u32);

impl <'a> SomeHandler<'a> {
    fn new(a: &'a u32) -> std::rc::Rc<Handler> {
        std::rc::Rc::new(SomeHandler(a))
    }
}

impl <'a> Handler for SomeHandler<'a> {
}

fn main() {
    let a: u32;
    SomeHandler::new(&a);
}
```

It fails with

```
8 |         std::rc::Rc::new(SomeHandler(a))
  |                                      ^
  = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
  = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
          expected std::rc::Rc<Handler + 'static>
             found std::rc::Rc<Handler>
```

#### Why explicit lifetimes do not work

The simple demo might be fixed by adding an explicit lifetime (e.g. `Rc<Handler + 'a>`).  Unfortunately, this is not an option (nor trying to make anything `'static`) because real code is intended to look like

```
struct PollRegistry {
    ...
    handlers: std::collections::HashMap<mio::Token, std::rc::Weak<PollHandler>>,
}

impl PollRegistry {
    fn register<'a>(&mut self, handler: &std::rc::Rc<PollHandler>,
                interest: mio::Ready, opts: mio::PollOpt)
                -> std::io::Result<()> {
        ....
        self.handlers.insert(token, std::rc::Rc::downgrade(handler));
    }
}
```

and methods in `PollHandler` specializations create and own other `PollHandler` specializations which are registered in the registry by these methods.

rustc 1.27.1

Comment: `fn new(a: &'a u32) -> std::rc::Rc<dyn Handler + 'a>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053550/the-compiler-suggests-i-add-a-static-lifetime-because-the-parameter-type-may-no)

Comment: @Boiethios works in demo code, but purpose if `Rc<>` indirection was to avoid lifetime specifications completely.

Comment: You cannot do that with the demo code because you most own the object to remove the lifetime specification. You **must** specify the lifetime of a reference. See the answer of the duplicate, it explains how to solve your issue.

Comment: @Boiethios I am 250% sure that I do not want to add a `'static` lifetime requirement somewhere in my code (because objects are allocated dynamically). Things are fine when I return `Rc<SomeHandler>` directly (but rest breaks) and specifying lifetimes like `Rc<... + 'a>` is not possible because `add()` will be called e.g. from functions of the trait objects itself to create other handlers (which are owned by the calling object).

Comment: Did you read the answers of the duplicate? [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40053649/4498831) will help you to understand.

Comment: *a `'static` lifetime [...] because objects are allocated dynamically* — That's not what `'static` means. It basically means that the returned type will not contain any references. If the returned type *did* contain a reference, then it couldn't live longer than the referenced value, that's a giant purpose of the Rust language. Perhaps you are interested in using `Rc` / `Arc` to have lighter-weight shared copies a value.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes, I am already using `Rc<>`, but rust seems to require an explicit lifetime parameter when working with traits (which is not the case when using "normal" objects).

Comment: Perhaps you could read over [Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42028470/155423) if you don't understand that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028470/why-is-adding-a-lifetime-to-a-trait-with-the-plus-operator-iteratoritem-foo)

Comment: I think your question is answered clearly by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42028805/3650362) (the `'static` appears by default on trait objects when you don't provide a lifetime). Your "real code" with the `PollRegistry` might have other issues -- why have the `'a` lifetime parameter at all if you're not going to use it? -- but if you want help with that, please make a [mcve] so that we can tell what you're dealing with. You might be trying to do something unsound.