# Lifetime of returned Boxed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and thought I'd try to make a very simple reactive stream library. A sample of the code is below:

```
trait Observable<T> {
    // some stuff for emitting values when requested
}

trait Mappable<T, U> {
    fn map(self, f: fn(&T) -> U) -> Box<dyn Observable<U>>;
}

struct Just<T> {
    value: T
}

impl<T> Observable<T> for Just<T> {}

impl<T, U: 'static> Mappable<T, U> for Just<T> {
    fn map(self, f: fn(&T) -> U) -> Box<dyn Observable<U>> {
        Box::new(Just { value: f(&self.value) })
    }
}
```

In order to make it work, I need to give a `'static` lifetime to the `U` type in the implementation of `Mappable` for `Just`. Without it, the compiler complains:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `U` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:17:9
   |
15 |   impl<T, U> Mappable<T, U> for Just<T> {
   |           - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `U: 'static`...
16 |       fn map(self, f: fn(&T) -> U) -> Box<dyn Observable<U>> {
17 | /         Box::new(Just {
18 | |             value: f(&self.value),
19 | |         })
   | |__________^
   |
note: ...so that the type `Just<U>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:17:9
   |
17 | /         Box::new(Just {
18 | |             value: f(&self.value),
19 | |         })
   | |__________^
```

I don't understand why the compiler is complaining about this because the value is placed inside a `Box`.

Providing the `'static` lifetime obviously works but I'm concerned that it would create a memory leak as intermediate stages in the stream would not be free'd until the program exits.

I think the solution is to make the lifetime of `U` be the same as `T`. But all my attempts at doing this have failed.

How can I express the above code without using `'static`?

Comment: It looks like you think that `'static` here means that the boxed value will live forever, but that is when it refers to references. Here, it constraints a type, it just means that `U` will not contain non-static references.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=149b51e36b4be4956e9a9ad9c382fd96&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: @Shepmaster it looks like your rust example does the trick, now I just have to read up on this syntax:  `dyn Observable<U> + 'a`

Comment: @Oli I added a duplicate Q for what the syntax is: [Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42028470/155423).