# How to put a reference to a trait object in an Option?

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

I'd like to store a reference to an `io::Write` trait object inside an `Option` in a struct but I can't figure out how. I can put the reference in directly like this:

```
pub struct Parameters<'a> {
    pub log: &'a (io::Write + 'a),
    // Other elements removed
}
```

and then assign it from (for example) a `BufWriter` like this:

```
let logstream = &BufWriter::new(f);
let parameters = Parameters {
    log: logstream, // Other elements removed
};
```

This works, but I'd like the `logstream` to be optional. If I try:

```
pub struct Parameters<'a> {
    pub log: Option<&'a(io::Write + 'a)>,
    // Other elements removed
}
```

and

```
let logstream = match f {
    Some(f) => Some(&BufWriter::new(f)),
    None => None,
};

let parameters = Parameters {
    log: logstream,
    // Other elements removed
};
```

I get:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:14
   |
17 |         log: logstream,
   |              ^^^^^^^^^ expected trait std::io::Write, found struct `std::io::BufWriter`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::option::Option<&dyn std::io::Write>`
              found type `std::option::Option<&std::io::BufWriter<std::vec::Vec<u8>>>`
```

What is a suitable approach here?

Comment: Once you get this past the type checker, the borrow checker will kill you (the `BufWriter` doesn't live long enough).

Answer (score 0):

You have to somehow explicitly type the `BufWriter` with the trait type, and you also have to be more careful with lifetimes.

Here is a sketch of how this could work:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::BufWriter;
use std::str::from_utf8;

pub struct Parameters<'a> {
    pub log: Option<&'a mut io::Write>,
    // Other elements removed
}

fn main() {
    let mut w = BufWriter::new(Vec::new());
    let rw: &mut std::io::Write = &mut w;
    let logstream = Some(rw);

    let parameters = Parameters {
        log: logstream,
        // Other elements removed
    };
    parameters.log.unwrap().write(b"hello world").ok();

    println!("{}", from_utf8(&w.into_inner().unwrap()).unwrap());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, starblue. Actually, I think I may have found another answer using Option<Box<dyn std::io::Write>> - I'll post it here for comment once I've finished checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::BufWriter;

pub struct P<'a> {
    pub log: Option<&'a mut io::Write>,
}

fn file() -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
    Some(Vec::new())
}

fn main() {
    let mut ow = file().map(|f| BufWriter::new(f));
    let p = P {
        log: ow.as_mut().map(|w| w as &mut io::Write),
    };

    p.log.unwrap().write(b"Hi!").ok();

    println!(
        "{}",
        String::from_utf8(ow.unwrap().into_inner().unwrap()).unwrap()
    );
}
```

Rather than taking an `Option<W>` and try and convert it into an `Option<&mut io::Write>` in one go, do it in three steps:

- `Option<W>` -> `Option<io::BufWriter<W>>` to make `ow`.  This is the thing that will own the `BufWriter`.  As pointed out in the other answer, if you try and create a `BufWriter` within the pattern match and then immediately take a reference to it, that reference's lifetime is scoped within the branch of the pattern match, so the borrow checker will complain.
- The next step is to convert from `Option<io::BufWriter<W>>` to `Option<&mut io::BufWriter<W>>` using `as_mut()`.
- Finally convert from a reference to the implementation, to the generic trait object.  In this case with a map containing a cast.  I had tried using `into`, but there doesn't seem to be an implementation for convert between a reference to the implementor of a trait and a reference to the trait object.

In this example, `file()` returns a `Vec<u8>` as the underlying writer, I did this so that the solution was [testable in a Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fbc3b8ff36c2753779e38e5aa0aa5e6f), but this could as well be a `File`.

Finally, I removed the lifetime constraint on the trait object, the type system/borrow checker didn't seem to think it was necessary.

Comment: *removed the lifetime constraint on the trait object* — [Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42028470/155423)

Comment: You are allowed to read and write to the filesystem in the playground.

Comment: @Shepmaster, that's good to know!  Here is a [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66c62e25e7a496706390b68364afd092) using a file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers above. Prior to them being posted I had an idea myself and came up with this (cut down to a minimal example that shows more or less what I'm trying to do):

```
use std::{env, process};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufWriter};

pub struct Parameters {
    pub log: Option<Box<dyn io::Write>>,
}


fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let logfile = if args.len() > 1 {
        Some(&args[1])
    } else {
        None
    };

    let logstream: Option<Box<dyn io::Write>> = match logfile {
        Some(logfile) => {
            let f = File::create(logfile).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
                eprintln!("ERROR opening logfile: {}", err);
                process::exit(1);
            });
            let logstream = BufWriter::new(f);
            Some(Box::new(logstream))
        }
        None => {
            None
        },
    };

    let parameters = Parameters {
        log: logstream,
    };
    play(parameters);
}

fn play(parameters: Parameters) {
    // Rest of code removed
    if let Some(mut stream) = parameters.log {
        stream.write("Testing\n".as_bytes()).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
            eprintln!("ERROR writing to logfile: {}", err);
            process::exit(1);
        });
    }
}
```

Is this a good solution or would one of the ones suggested above be better?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as originally posed: *How to put a **reference** to a trait object in an `Option`?*

Comment: Rust has an extremely rich standard library that captures a lot of the idioms that you've written from scratch here.  For example, you can use `env::args().nth(1)` to optionally get the 1st argument, and rather than using `process::exit`, I would change the return type of `main` to `io::Result<()>` and use the `?` operator to propagate the error.  Here's an adapted [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fe8288d55cf505f1c156362a6b7e1141)

Comment: @Shepmaster - Thanks for your help. Maybe this doesn't really answer the question as written, though as I understand it a Box is a type of reference to an object on the heap. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough as this did achieve what I needed - to optionally create the writer externally to my library and pass it in.

Comment: @amnn - Thanks for the tip about args().nth(1) - I'm still learning Rust and the library is large so it takes a while to realise these things exist. As for the process::exit() - yes, that was just for a quick-and-dirty demo - usually I would return a Result() object and use ? (I use ? quite extensively in my real code)