# How to solve lifetime conflict in closure?

Tags: rust

I use a closure as callback function called from an external library (with libloading). This closure is using a variable from the parent function to resolve an asynchrone function (in V8 engine). But I am getting an error from the compiler `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter 'sc due to conflicting requirements`.

```
// main.rs

use rusty_v8 as v8;
extern crate libloading as lib;

pub fn main() {
  let platform = v8::new_default_platform().unwrap();
  v8::V8::initialize_platform(platform);
  v8::V8::initialize();
  let mut isolate = v8::Isolate::new(Default::default());
  let mut handle_scope = v8::HandleScope::new(&mut isolate);
  let scope = handle_scope.enter();

  let object_templ = v8::ObjectTemplate::new(scope);
  let function_templ = v8::FunctionTemplate::new(scope, core_instantiate_async);
  let name = v8::String::new(scope, "coreInstantiateAsync").unwrap();
  object_templ.set(name.into(), function_templ.into());

  let context = v8::Context::new_from_template(scope, object_templ);
  let mut cs = v8::ContextScope::new(scope, context);
  let scope = cs.enter();

  let code = v8::String::new(scope, "coreInstantiateAsync('adder');").unwrap();

  let mut script = v8::Script::compile(scope, context, code, None).unwrap();
  let result = script.run(scope, context).unwrap();
  let result = result.to_string(scope).unwrap();
  println!("result: {}", result.to_rust_string_lossy(scope));
}

pub fn core_instantiate_async(
    scope: v8::FunctionCallbackScope,
    args: v8::FunctionCallbackArguments,
    mut rv: v8::ReturnValue,
) {
    let context = scope.get_current_context().unwrap();
    let resolver = v8::PromiseResolver::new(scope, context).unwrap();
    let promise = resolver.get_promise(scope);

    let mut resolver_handle = v8::Global::new();
    resolver_handle.set(scope, resolver);
    {
        instantiate_async(
            scope,
            context,
            resolver_handle,
        );
    }

    rv.set(promise.into());
}

type RunAsyncFunc = unsafe fn(cb: Box<dyn FnMut(Option<String>)>);

pub fn instantiate_async<'a>(
    scope: &mut impl v8::ToLocal<'a>,
    context: v8::Local<'a, v8::Context>,
    mut resolver_handle: v8::Global<v8::PromiseResolver>,
) {
    let resolver = resolver_handle.get(scope).unwrap();
    resolver_handle.reset(scope);
    let cb = |response: Option<String>| {
        if let Some(res) = response {
            let value = v8::String::new(scope, &res).unwrap();
            resolver.resolve(context, value.into()).unwrap();
        } else {
            resolver
               .resolve(context, v8::undefined(scope).into())
               .unwrap();
        }
    };

    let plugin = lib::Library::new("./my_lib.so").unwrap();
    let run_async: lib::Symbol<RunAsyncFunc> = plugin.get(b"run_async").unwrap();
    run_async(Box::new(cb));
}
```

```
# Cargo.toml

[package]
name = "example"
version = "0.0.1"
edition = "2018"
default-run = "example"

[[bin]]
name = "example"
path = "main.rs"

[dependencies]
rusty_v8 = "0.5.0"
libloading = "0.5.0"
```

When I run `cargo build` I get this error:

```sh
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'sc` due to conflicting requirements
  --> main.rs:58:36
   |
58 |     let resolver = resolver_handle.get(scope).unwrap();
   |                                    ^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the function body at 53:26...
  --> main.rs:53:26
   |
53 | pub fn instantiate_async<'a>(
   |                          ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> main.rs:58:36
   |
58 |     let resolver = resolver_handle.get(scope).unwrap();
   |                                    ^^^
   = note: expected  `rusty_v8::scope_traits::ToLocal<'_>`
              found  `rusty_v8::scope_traits::ToLocal<'a>`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> main.rs:73:15
   |
73 |     run_async(Box::new(cb));
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected  `std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::ops::FnMut(std::option::Option<std::string::String>) + 'static)>`
              found  `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::FnMut(std::option::Option<std::string::String>)>`
```

And my_lib.so:

```
#[no_mangle]
fn run_async(cb: Box<dyn FnMut(Option<String>)>) {
    println!("run_async");
    let mut cb = cb;
    cb(Some("callback response".to_string()));
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Could you reduce this code to a [reprex], which focuses on the problem?

Comment: This is the minimal reproducible example that I am able to provide, else my knowledge in Rust are not good enough to reduce it to something more generic -.-

Comment: @E_net4isrenamedallthetime I will try your suggestion. I updated my post to include the code of my_lib.so

Comment: @E_net4isrenamedallthetime thx a lot, it seem to work. I am really happy about your help cause I am stuck on this since 2 days. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, duplicate: [Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028470/why-is-adding-a-lifetime-to-a-trait-with-the-plus-operator-iteratoritem-foo)